# Cannot import spring mvc project property into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am trying to import the project at http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2009/jw-springmvc-cms-src.zip into eclipse.

I do File -> New -> Project.. -> Java Project From Existing Ant Buildfile. I give the path of the build.xml of the project.

It imports the project into eclipse and shows the src and test folders. However, it does not show the WEB-INF, css etc. folders. Why? How can they also be viewed in the project structure in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try creating "by hand" the missing folders into your newly created project, then you can use Import -> File system to add the missing files into the respective folders...